# Uninitialized Array in C programming

Tags: c, arrays, computer-science, garbage

I'm confused about uninitialised array. Whenever I initialised an array like this `int array[10];`, and don't apply any values, and then print this uninitialised array. The first element of this array will always be a garbage value ( like `printf("%d",array[0]);` will be some garbage value). But other values such as from `array[1]` to `array[10]` will be by default initialised as `zero(0)`.

Can anyone explain why ?

Comment: `int array[10];` That defines an array but in no way does it initialise it (assuming it isn't a global/static variable). "But other values such as from array[1] to array[10] will be by default initialized as zero(0)". No they won't.  Accessing unintialised variables is Undefined Behaviour and just because you saw 0 does not mean it will always be 0.

Comment: Also, please take some care regarding what tags you use for your question. Only use language tags that are relevant. For example, it is not clear why `python` is used for this question.

Comment: Re "*other values such as from array[1] to array[10]*", There is no `array[10]` in an `int array[10];`. Accessing `array[10]` is undefined behaviour. Array indexes are offsets, so they go from 0 to 9 for `int array[10];`

Answer (score 3):

```
int array[10]; // defined, not initialized
int array[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}; // defined and initialized
```

Answer (score 1):

Stack based array - array[1] being 0 is just a random coincident. Unless you explicitly zero-clear, the values are undefined. BTW, array[10] is out-of-bounds when the size of array is 10.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/arrays-cpp?view=vs-2019

If you do not assign a default value, each element will initially contain whatever random values happen to be at that location.

Comment: Providing C++ documentation to answer a C question is suboptimal.